# SQLBulkCopy.WriteToServer DataTable way to write portions of data to the tables?

Tags: vba, datatable

I have like 12,000 rows in a DataTable and it is timing out when trying to WriteToServer.  Is there a way I can write just a portion of the DataTable at a time to the database rather than all at once?  I have a bad internet connection to my database at the moment.  If I can just write 500 rows at a time, I can avoid the timeout.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The source stream should be under your control (if it isn't then insert your own code between it and the SQLBulkCopy).  Just count rows to 500 and then cut off the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at `SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize`

> A batch is complete when BatchSize rows have been processed or there
>   are no more rows to send to the destination data source.
>
> Zero (the default) indicates that each WriteToServer operation is a
>   single batch.
>
> If the SqlBulkCopy instance has been declared without the
>   UseInternalTransaction option in effect, rows are sent to the server
>   BatchSize rows at a time, but no transaction-related action is taken.
>   If UseInternalTransaction is in effect, each batch of rows is inserted
>   as a separate transaction.
>
> The BatchSize property can be set at any time. If a bulk copy is
>   already in progress, the current batch is sized according to the
>   previous batch size. Subsequent batches use the new size. If the
>   BatchSize is initially zero and changed while a WriteToServer
>   operation is already in progress, that operation loads the data as a
>   single batch. Any subsequent WriteToServer operations on the same
>   SqlBulkCopy instance use the new BatchSize.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!!  Thank you very much for your help!!  Your are a life saver!!

Comment: No problem. @user840930 :Remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings :P

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I simply solved it doing like this:

```
Dim strConnection as string="myconnectionstring"
Dim sqlBulk As New SqlBulkCopy(strConnection)
sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
```